# Error in calculating the angle of a line

Tags: 2d, line, angle

I tried to calculate the angle between my start position and end position, but it keeps a number between 2 and -2. I got this code from stack overflow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676719/calculating-the-angle-between-the-line-defined-by-two-points) and intergrated it in my GridClass. Does anyone know what's wrong with this code?

```
public static double getAngle(GeoPosition startPosition, GeoPosition endPosition)
{

double a_x = endPosition.getLatitude() - startPosition.getLatitude();
double a_y = endPosition.getLongitude() - startPosition.getLongitude();

return Math.atan2(a_y, a_x);
}
```

Comment: Really should study math before trying to learn programming.

Comment: @drysdam: That was my first guess, too, but then there should be values "between -3 and 3"...

Comment: No, arctangent only returns values between -π/2 and π/2.

Comment: Oh, you're right - so it's actually between -1.6 and 1.6...

Answer (score 0):

> **but it keeps a number between 2 and -2**

The trigonometry methods in Java use radians. If you need degrees (0-360) use [`Math.toDegrees`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toDegrees%28double%29):

> *Converts an angle measured in radians to an approximately equivalent angle measured in degrees.*