# Calculate angle between two lines

Tags: java, android, canvas, trigonometry

After looking at the answers provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676719/calculating-the-angle-between-the-line-defined-by-two-points) question, I created the following method:

```
private int angleOf(float x1, float x2, float y1, float y2) {
    final double deltaY = (y1 - y2);
    final double deltaX = (x2 - x1);
    final double result = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX));
    return (int) ((result < 0) ? (360d + result) : result);
}
```

by using the above I will get the angle of each line , then I draw the text to my canvas, as shown below:

```
int topLine = angleOf(this.mPoints[5].x, this.mPoints[4].x, this.mPoints[5].y, this.mPoints[4].y);
int bottomLine = angleOf(this.mPoints[5].x, this.mPoints[6].x, this.mPoints[5].y, this.mPoints[6].y);

canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(360 - bottomLine + topLine)+"°", this.mPoints[5].x - 80.0f, this.mPoints[5].y, this.mTextPaint);
```

---

The above works fine, here is a example of my result:

[image: exampleImage1]

---

The problem I have is that the angle is measured from the x-axis and increasing anti-clockwise, as shown below:

[image: image2]

When the bottom line or the top line "crosses" the 0° (parallel to the x-axis), I would then get an incorrect angle.

Here is another image to demonstrate this issue:

[image: image3]

The angle between the blue lines are 90°, but instead I get 450°. This happens because of the calculation I used `360 - bottomLine + topLine`.

Can someone please suggest a solution to this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: `(360 - topLine + bottomLine) % 360 ` or something similar

Comment: @pskink , your comment will work ideally.

Comment: @KaranMer i hope so, because i did not test it ;-)

Comment: You are calculating the angle between the line through `(x1,y1)` and `(x2, y2)`, and the x-axis. I'm guessing this isn't what you intend.

Comment: @pskink I tested and I still get the wrong angle. For my test I set the `topLine` to 31 degrees and the `bottomLine` to 338 degrees. So the calculation will be `(360 - 31 + 338) % 360` this will give me 1.85

Comment: `(360 - 31 + 338) % 360` gives `307`, not `1.85` - `%` is a [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), not divide

Comment: `%` is a [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), not divide, for example `36 % 10 == 6`, and not `3.6`

Comment: @pskink Ah I see, thank you so much. It is working as expected.

Comment: good, your welcome

Answer (score 1):

*You can use like this,out put value is **radian** 
coordinate point (0,0) other points (x1,y1) ,(x2,y2)*

`atan()` = tan invers

```
private double angleOfRadian(float x1, float x2, float y1, float y2) {
     return java.lang.Math.atan(y2/x2)-java.lang.Math.atan(y1/x1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to calculate it properly:

```
private double angleOfDegrees(float x0, float y0, float x1, float y1) {
    double angle2 = Math.atan2(y1,x1);
    double angle1 = Math.atan2(y0,x0);

   return Math.toDegrees(angle2 - angle1) + 360) % 360;
}
```